# Weird thing 2 days ago I have 700 records in my table ..now its showing more

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table in a MySQL database. In this table, I checked the number of records via an auto-incrementing ID field, the total was 700.  2 days later it's showing 7000 and when I add any data it increases by 1 to 7001, 7002... and so on.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could it be that you were adding records?

Comment: no i m not adding tht much data only 1 -2

Comment: Sorry for my english. problem i m facing is my records which were 700 in mysql database suddenly started showing 7000, now its increasing whenever i m adding record in tht table

Comment: You have to provide more information than that. How do you guess we should know anything about your database? Put yourself in the position of people who know nothing about your problem.

Comment: Still, this is a fair question. It doesn't deserve this amount of downvotes. @ansh try adding more detail

Comment: @ansh: You mean the ID-field max is 7000, but not the amount of records? I think this is a valid question too. If you have deleted records it will not "lower" the ID-sequence, say you created 10 records, they would have IDs 1, 2, ... 10. If you now delete 2, and add one, the last one will have the ID 11. Is this what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` option of your table was probably set to `7000` - for whatever reason. This causes MySQL to use that as the ID value for the next inserted row. It does not give any information on the number of rows. You could set it to seven billion, if you wanted to.

To obtain the number of rows in a table use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`.

Comment: i run tht sql its showing 7312 but i cant enter tht much records alone in a day or two ..

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is on 7486 is it because of that ? can i make it to 1 ?

Comment: @ansh: Yes you can, but that'll give you an error, because ID 1 is already taken. I would just leave the ID as is. The size of the ID should be unimportant for functioning of your application.

Answer (score 2):

how about select count(*) from the table instead of looking at the id field.  that would at least tell you how many real records there are

Answer (score 1):

You mean the ID-field max is 7000, but not the amount of records?

If you have deleted records it will not "lower" the ID-sequence, say you created 10 records, they would have IDs 1, 2, ... 10. If you now delete 2, and add one, the last one will have the ID 11. Is this what is happening?